# Android : static String get Last Outgoing Call() method

Tags: java, android

I'd like to use the `static String getLastOutgoingCall()` method in order to pull the duration of the last outgoing phone call but I don't know how !
I'm a beginner with java programming (I usually program in c++)

The tutorials that I found use the ancient APIs  and none of them use the method I'm talking about.

Answer (score 2):

I hope I have not misinterpreted your question. If so, please let me know.

The method `String getLastOutgoingCall (Context context)` from `android.provider.CallLog.Calls`, according to [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CallLog.Calls.html#getLastOutgoingCall(android.content.Context)), returns

> The last phone number dialed (outgoing) or an empty string if none
>   exist yet.

So, you can't retrieve the last outgoing call duration using that method.

To get the last outgoing call duration, you can query the `CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI` to retrieve this info.

You can use a method like this:

```
public String getLastOutgoingCallDuration(final Context context) {
    String output = null;

    final Uri callog = CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI;
    Cursor cursor = null;

    try {
        // Query all the columns of the records that matches "type=2"
        // (outgoing) and orders the results by "date"
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(callog, null,
                CallLog.Calls.TYPE + "=" + CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE,
                null, CallLog.Calls.DATE);
        final int durationCol = cursor
                .getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION);

        // Retrieve only the last record to get the last outgoing call
        if (cursor.moveToLast()) {
            // Retrieve only the duration column
            output = cursor.getString(durationCol);
        }
    } finally {
        // Close the resources
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }

    return output;
}
```

Note: To perform this query you will need to add the following permission to your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
```

---

Edit based on your own answer:

You need to call the `getLastOutgoingCallDuration()` on the `onCreate()` method of your Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main); // Here you need to set the name of your xml

    TextView displayDuration;
    displayDuration = (TextView)  findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    String duration = getLastOutgoingCallDuration(this);

    displayDuration.setText(output + "sec");
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much this is exactly what I'm looking for, I didn't read very well the documentation. I'm not currently on my computer I'll let you know if it worked !

Comment: duration is not perfect.sometimes it is higher than actual.