# Android Get last outgoing call duration

Tags: java, android

I would like to get the duration of the last outgoing call whenever I open my application. All the codes I tried didn't work in practice...                             Can someone provide me a good code for this ?

Comment: You say "everything you've tried didn't work" - could you give some examples of what you tried please?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19493360/get-last-call-duration-in-android
This is a Duplicate question.

Comment: You will find it here : 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30080786/android-static-string-get-last-outgoing-call-method